# Returning a Promise from graphql React HOC

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a form, it is meant to be used to edit existing resources in my app. I have a React component which is wrapped in the `graphql` HOC in the following way:

```
import {compose, graphql} from 'react-apollo';

// ...

const withData = compose(
  graphql(FetchEditorData, {
    props(p) {
      preloadEditorData() => {
        // this function is meant to return a promise with the desired data
        // the documentation only explains what p.data contains (i.e. loading,
        // data etc.)
      },
    },
  },
  graphql(CommitResourceEditMutation, {
    props(p) {
      onSubmit(editorState) => { /* ... */ },
  },
);

export default withData(ResourceEditor);
```

As you can see, the components reads data from a query, loads it into the form and when the form is submitted, the mutation is executed.

I need to display a loading indicator both when the data is loading and when the changes are saving. By following the traditional approach the [docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html) state, I would need to add a **`loading` prop** and a **`loading` state key** and check on both of them.

Instead, I added a property to my component, `preloadEditorData` which is meant to return a `Promise<EditorState>`, so I can have only one `loading` flag. Is there any way I can return a Promise from the HOC?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of this. It's done for you! 
Check if `data.networkStatus` is `1`. That means your data is loading. When it is `7` it is complete.

More info:http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-query-data-networkStatus

Comment: I think you have misread my question. The whole purpose of this is not to have two `loading` flags; I don't care that's been already done for me.